# Discrete mathematics Proof (∃y ∈ A, P y) ∨ (∃y ∈ A, Qy) =⇒ ∃x ∈ A, P x ∨ Qx with coq or by hand

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

(∃y ∈ A, P y) ∨ (∃y ∈ A, Qy) =⇒ ∃x ∈ A, P x ∨ Qx is a school hw problem of mine, and I haven't encountered something of this nature yet and I' not sure where to start really. So if anyone is good at teaching this stuff or knows a great resource to familiarize myself with this that would be great. If you just want to show it in the proof assistant that is also helpful, but i would really like how to understand how to do these.

I'm sorry if the way this is worded breaks tos ahead of time, I'm rather new to these stack sites, A friend of mine told me about them but said to be careful.

Comment: This isn't a "do my homework site."  We're quite happy to help you when someone has difficulties, but first we like to see what efforts you have made to guage your level of understanding and identify exactly what is causing trouble.  "I don't know what I'm doing," doesn't give us much to work with.  Make an attempt at solving it using whatever proof techniques you've been taught in class, recently.   (At least tell us what proof system you are working with.)

Comment: I understand that, I'm not trying to just get the answer anyways since its not graded. I was more hoping of seeing the first step I might understand where to go from this. Our professor does all his work in the proofing assistant, but its not helpful if he doesent explain what each of those function do. As for where I'm stuck Im not sure how to imply the x's from the y's. I can read the problem out loud in english So I understand what each symbol means. I just dont get how i can imply that there exists an x in a which Px or Qx is true from knowing that there exists a y in Py or Qy that gives T

Comment: oh and i thought i put that we use coq in class, my bad.